# Отловить программное изменение input'a

Tags: jquery, javascript

Возможно ли с помощью jquery отловить изменение значения input'a заданного программно?
Если нет, то как это возможно и возможно ли вообще (без сильных танцев с бубном)?

Функция change отлавливает изменение только через интерфейс, вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/VHgkN/4/):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="xxx"/>
<button onclick="$('#test').val('xaxaxa');">Click Me</button>​
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').change(
        function(){alert($(this).val())});
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо всем, натолкнули на правильные мысли. Вопрос решил [так](http://jsfiddle.net/VHgkN/21/):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="xxx"/>
<button id='button'>Click Me</button>​
```

**JS**

```
var oldVal = $.fn.val;
$.fn.oldVal = oldVal;

$.fn.val = function(value){
    if(!value)
        return this.oldVal();
    else
    {
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).oldVal(value);
            $(this).change();
        });
    }

};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });

    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#test').val('xaxaxa'); 
    });
});
​
```

Жду критики.

Comment: ну или так сделать )   это то за что я люблю js )

единственно то что в принцепе можно это

var oldVal = $.fn.val;
$.fn.oldVal = oldVal;

заменить на 

$.fn.oldVal = $.fn.val;

Comment: это безусловно плюс, но почему? oldVal ссылается на val, который вы переопределили, почему oldVal не переопределился?

Comment: а также использовать return $("#test").val.call(this, arguments);

Comment: @MuFF, а это для чего и почему(val.call...)? 
@Spectre, видимо не ссылается, точнее ссылается на функцию, а переопределили мы свойство fn

Comment: чёт я туплю, всё верно у вас:

    var func1 = function(){return 1;}
    var func2 = func1;
    func1 = function(){return 2;}
    func2(); // 1

Answer (score -1):

Это уже похоже на неправильную архитектуру. Наверное, Вы много раз слышали, что значения в объекты не должны устанавливаться напрямую в свойства или считываться с объектов напрямую из свойств - для этого лучше всегда использовать геттеры и сеттеры.

Здесь похожая ситуация. Если Вы предполагаете, что функция, которую Вы не сможете изменить, будет вызываться из такого количества мест, что даже представить не можете откуда, то лучшее обернуть в свою.

Поэтому просто оберни `$('#test').val('xaxaxa');` в свою функцию и через нее всегда изменять `#test`.

Comment: А val разве не является аналогом сеттера/геттера? :-) Представить откуда будет вызывать я то как раз могу, поэтому и хочу отлавливать этот момент написанием одной строчки, а не замены пары тысяч :-) На крайняк это тоже вариант, но я бы не назвал это решение красивым и правельным. 

Ваше решение вааще не годиться и более того аргументы мне сильно не импонируют. Как Вы предлагаете обернуть #test ? аля $("#test").myVal("lala") ? Идея в том что на изменения значения #test вешается определённый функционал, а как это изменение произошло - не важно.

Comment: .val() функция из сторонней библиотеки, которую вы используете в своем коде. Нельзя менять код сторонней библиотеки. Это плохая привычка. Да, вы можете сейчас поменять и далее работая над проектом вы будите это знать, да и js это позволяет. Но не приучайте себя мыслить таким образом. Другой человек, который будет работать над кодом после Вас не поймет что вы хотели этим сказать. Менять чужой код это плохо. Расширять его функциональность нужно только наследованием или чемто вроде того.

Comment: А никто и не хочет менять код jquery, даже мысли не было :-) Менять чужой код нужно, если его уже никто менять не зависимо от Вас не собирается, а Вас он не устраивает, и это не "чёрный ящик".

Answer (score -1):

А просто сделать триггер события ?...

```
<button onclick="$('#test').val('xaxaxa');('#test').trigger('change');">Click Me</button>​
```

Comment: Уже обсуждалось, товарищ @Spectre предлагал этот вариант в той или иной форме. Почему это не подходит можно подчерпнуть из комментариев.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('select, input, textarea, button').change(function(){
            alert('Что-то изменилось...');
        });

});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.