# Как отследить вызов функции jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если использовать `val()`, то `on('change')` не работает. Я хочу написать функцию, которая вызывается после выполнения `val()`, в ней проверяется - у какого элемента была вызвана `val()`. И если это нужный мне элемент, то происходит `trigger('change')`. Как такое сделать?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вам нужно. Можете привести конкретный пример?

Comment: У меня на input стоит событие - on('change'). Но оно не срабатывает, если я меняю значение input через ф-ию val(). Так понятнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необязательно придумывать какую-то новую функцию. Достаточно после вызова функции `val()` дописать `.trigger('change')` (или просто `.change()`) - это "даст сигнал" вашему обработчику события `change` и выполнит код, описанный в нем:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('input').val(str_rand()).trigger('change');
});

/* ДЛЯ ДЕМОНСТРАЦИИ */
var changed = 0;
$('.input').on('change', function() { // обработчик change
  changed++;
  $('.changed').text('Изменено ' + changed + ' раз');
});

function str_rand() { // случайный набор символов
  var result = '';
  var words = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
  var max_position = words.length - 1;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    position = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_position);
    result = result + words.substring(position, position + 1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" /><br />
<button class="val1">val()</button>
<div class="changed"></div>
```

---

Если же возможности прописать триггер нет (например, если функция `.val()` вызывается из стороннего скрипта), можно немного переписать функцию `.val()`:

Решение, как оказалось, лежало [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/131594/209956), но, к сожалению, без пояснений.

```js
var oldVal = $.fn.val; // переопределяем функцию .val()
$.fn.oldVal = oldVal; // на .oldVal()
$.fn.val = function(value) { // и определяем новый функционал .val()
  if (!value) { // если value пустое
    return this.oldVal(); // возвращаем текущее value
  } else {
    this.oldVal(value).trigger('change'); // задаем value по аналогии со "старой" .val() и вызываем событие change
  }
};

/* ДЛЯ ДЕМОНСТРАЦИИ */
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('input').val(str_rand());
});

var changed = 0;
$('.input').on('change', function() { // обработчик change
  changed++;
  $('.changed').text('Изменено ' + changed + ' раз');
});

function str_rand() { // случайный набор символов
  var result = '';
  var words = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
  var max_position = words.length - 1;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    position = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_position);
    result = result + words.substring(position, position + 1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" value="val" />
<button class="change">val()</button>
<div class="changed"></div>
```

---

Как вариант, но, наверное, самый неправильный - можно запустить постоянную проверку через `setTimeout()`.

**ВАЖНО** учитывать, что такой вариант довольно сильно нагрузит браузер, вследствие чего снизится производительность.

```js
$('.input').each(function() {
  var inp = $(this),
    old = inp.val(); // старое value
  setInterval(function() {
    if (inp.val() !== old) { // если новое value не равно старому
      inp.trigger('change'); // вызываем событие change
      old = inp.val(); // и переписываем старое value
    }
  }, 100);
});

/* ДЛЯ ДЕМОНСТРАЦИИ */
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('input').val(str_rand());
});

var changed = 0;
$('.input').on('change', function() { // обработчик change
  changed++;
  $('.changed').text('Изменено ' + changed + ' раз');
});

function str_rand() { // случайный набор символов
  var result = '';
  var words = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
  var max_position = words.length - 1;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    position = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_position);
    result = result + words.substring(position, position + 1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" value="val" />
<button class="change">val()</button>
<div class="changed"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня много мест, где вызывается функция val(). И в каждой ставить .trigger не очень удобно.

Comment: @Alexandr Nevajno, ну как бы ... либо так, либо через setInterval проверяйте значение, вам решать.

Comment: @MedvedevDev что довольно сильно нагрузит браузер, особенно, если отслеживаемых инпутов много

Comment: @Cheg, ну, видимо это лучше, чем через trigger ....

Comment: Я нашел вот такое решение:
var originalValFn = jQuery.fn.val;
jQuery.fn.val = function() {
    this.trigger('change');
    jQuery.fn.val.apply( this, arguments );
}
Только как определить, что вызывается val() именно с двумя аргументами? Я выводил arguments.length, но там либо 0, либо 1.

Comment: @AlexandrNevajno дополнил ответ вариант без нагрузки браузера. Уверен, это то, что вам нужно

Comment: `each` не нужен в коде

Comment: @Grundy в каком именно?

Comment: я только в одном месте вижу использование `each`: `return this.each(function() {`

Comment: @Grundy Есть еще `each` в свернутом сниппете. Вы имеете ввиду написать все в одну строчку `this.oldVal(value).trigger('change');` ?

Comment: я бы не стал добавлять `oldVal` в прототип, но в целом - да