# Как переписать методы jQuery?

Tags: jquery

У jQuery есть методы `text` и `html`, которые оперируют с DOM, но не проверяют что значения одинаковые. И записывают в DOM то же самое.
Было бы удобно иметь методы, которые бы проверяли не поменялось ли значение, и только если поменялось, то записывали бы его в DOM.
Вопрос в том, можно ли, не лезя в исходник, переписать эти методы?

Comment: Можете вот тут посмотреть - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716500/209956

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код jQuery пишет и анализирует настолько огромное сообщество, что если бы это имело практическую пользу эти функции именно так бы и написали.

Переписывать их своими силами не нужно, максимум напишите обёртку которая проверяет содержимое и подменяет его при надобности, прошу учесть что когда получаем контент из методов `$.html();` и `$.text();` он обычно содержит всевозможные пробелы и переносы строк, скорее всего потребуется что то вроде `$.trim();` или регулярки.

Если эта нужда из-за событий которые вы развесили, а потом подменили контент и события "потерялись", вешайте их на документ:
`$(document).on('click', '.classNode', function(){ });`

Если разговор все таки про производительность и лишнюю работу браузеру, то в этом случае "забейте", тк, прошу прощения, код jQuery однозначно более оптимален и производительнее вашего.

Comment: Чтобы не делать лишних проверок перед вызовом этих методов. Смысл то в том, что если текст не поменялся, то зачем тогда обновлять dom?

Comment: Движок браузера сам решит обновлять дом или нет, и если надобности нет то дом не обновится, а если все таки лишние пробелы и тд, то да, дом обновится но затраты будут меньше чем вы будете проходить регулярками и чистить мусор

Comment: Да не регулярками что то проверять. Смысл в простом сравнении строк. Браузеру идёт команда на обновление dom. Это надо предотвратить.

Comment: Да не сравните вы строки никогда, попробуйте посмотреть что у вас приходит на вход и что отдаёт $.html() они разные абсолютно, тк `domNode.innerHtml` содержит переносы строки и мусор, а $.trim() и  $.text() и вроде даже $.html() уже включают в себя регулярки, посмотрите исходники jQuery, и работает в 1000 раз медленнее чем обновление дома ( https://jsfiddle.net/5ex389wq/1/ )